# Apache2 rewrite URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, url-routing

I wanted to rewrite any request with www.example.org, https://www.example.org and http://example.org to https://example.org

Is there an easy way to do it?

I am currently doing the following in my .htaccess however the case of https://www.example.org -> https://example.org is not working.

1. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?
2. Also would it affect any search engine rankings because of this redirection.
3. Is this a best practice in URL redirection.

My current .htaccess looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.org
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# redirect for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI